# Postfix Dovecot Trusted TLS connection

Tags: postfix

i have been assigned a task to create a mail server for costumer, which will use it for sending mail to some company. Condition was that it needs to use trusted TLS connection. No matter what i did i couldn't get it to work, it was always untrusted when i was testing to send mail on gmail or Microsoft outlook.

In my `main.cf` i tried to:

- add: `smtp_tls_loglevel = 2`
- add: `smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainhere/fullchain.pem`
- add: `smtpd_tls_CApath=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomainhere/fullchain.pem`
- change: `smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt`

but all i was getting in roundcube was " Must issue a STARTTLS command first ", and in maillog there was nothing helpful, atleast to my knowledge. I surfed google for 3 days and no matter what i did i couldn't get to established Trusted TLS connection.

Does anyone have any ideas? i can provide more details.

Comment: What's your roundcube configuration? You need something like this in your roundcube configuration file: `$config['default_host'] = array('mail.example.com', 'webmail.example.com', 'ssl://mail.example.com:993');
`. Use either ssl:// or tls:// depending on the connection type

Comment: https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Configuration

Comment: i tried same thing with Mail client ( Mac's Mail program ). Mail was successfully sent, but it was Untrusted TLS connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from my postfix configuration file: /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mailserver.domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mailserver.domain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mailserver.domain.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl
```

I assume this is what you're aiming for:

```
Mar 12 15:34:36 mailserver postfix/smtp[61895]: Trusted TLS connection established to smtp.sendgrid.net[159.122.219.55]:587: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
```

Be sure to install the linux package called ca-certificates (I'm using CentOS so that's achieved by `yum -y install ca-certificates`)

The paths from my config are for CentOS-7.x

Comment: In this link, which you provided i want to create Trusted TLS connection, right now is Untrusted, and you have anonymous one.

Comment: You won't be able to do that for all the servers. You need to have the CA root certificates configured on your server

openssl s_client -showcerts -starttls smtp -connect remote-mail-server:25 and see the certificate chain. In this case you get the root certificate then you'll have to save it to your postfix config file: `smtp_tls_CAfile                 = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks, it is trusted TLS connection now, you saved me!

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could mark it as solved